# Get many connection using mysql_pconnect()

Tags: php, xampp, mysql-pconnect

I am using mysql_pconnect() for connecting to mysql.
But when many users uses the website it gives the error "To many connection with mysql".

For that i had set the variables
       max_connections=500 
       max_user_connections=1000 
   in my.cnf file of mysql.

Is this fine to use or is there any other way to solve this problem ("To many connection with mysql").

I am using the xampp for php and mysql.

Comment: You may use ZendServer CE with ZendFramework which have connection pool.There are no such problems like this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the way to increase the max connections. You can refer [here](http://www.thoughtlabs.com/2008/02/18/dealing-with-mysql-too-many-connections-error/) for more insights and as for using mysql_pconnect have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247807/mysql-connect-vs-mysql-pconnect)