# Difference between mysql_connect and mysql_pconnect?

Tags: php

The function mysql_connect() establishes the connection to MySQL. To establish the connection, the host name, database user and password is needed. The host is usually a localhost. But how To use mysql_pconnect?

Comment: I don't know the difference, only that you shouldn't use them, mysql is outdated and not secure

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_connect VS mysql\_pconnect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247807/mysql-connect-vs-mysql-pconnect) *but don't use either!* Use PDO instead, or mysqli_* if you really must.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same except for two major differences.

First, when connecting, the function would first try to find a (persistent) link that's already open with the same host, username and password. If one is found, an identifier for it will be returned instead of opening a new connection.

Second, the connection to the SQL server will not be closed when the execution of the script ends. Instead, the link will remain open for future use (mysql_close() will not close links established by mysql_pconnect()).

This type of link is therefore called 'persistent'.

Answer (score 0):

The hostname,username and password is also needed in `mysql_pconnect()` but the difference is simply like a shop when you entering you will open the door and take your item, come out and close the door this is called `mysql_connect()`, when code terminates, connection to mysql database will be automatically closed.

When the door of the shop is already opened and never closed it is called `mysql_pconnect()` , so it mean the connection to mysql database will not be closed and will `persist` for future use.